# How do you compute a CurseForge API fingerprint for a WoW Retail Addon?

Tags: api, rest, go, world-of-warcraft, murmurhash

There is no documentation on this.

I got as far as to understand that [Murmur2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash#MurmurHash2) is used for hashing stuff (that is not mentioned anywhere either..)

But I don't exactly know how to hash the addon.
Do I need to hash the filenames, the contents, what contents, all of them, in what order?

Can someone pls elaborate on a simple [example addon like this](https://mwcdn.co/walialu/wow-retail-addon-autorepair-20220309.zip)?

```
_retail_/Interface/Addons/AutoRepair/

.rw-rw-r-- 2.3k marco  9 Mar 20:22 AutoRepair.lua
.rw-rw-r--  249 marco  9 Mar 20:22 AutoRepair.toc
.rw-rw-r--  371 marco  9 Mar 20:22 AutoRepair.xml
```

What needs to be done to get the fingerprint hash that I can send to the [CF API](https://docs.curseforge.com/#curseforge-core-api-fingerprints) to get the exact match for the mod?

My current approach was to hash the contents of the files, order these fingerprints asc, append them to a string in that order and hash that string to get the final fingerprint.

But that did not yield any success, when querying the API with that fingerprint.

### Current Approach

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    mm "github.com/mistweaverco/go-murmur/murmur2"
)

func ReadFileAsBytes(path string) []byte {
    b, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return b
}

func GetFileListRecursive(dir string) []string {
    files := []string{}
    fileInfos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, fileInfo := range fileInfos {
        if fileInfo.IsDir() {
            files = append(files, GetFileListRecursive(dir+fileInfo.Name()+"/")...)
        } else {
            files = append(files, dir+fileInfo.Name())
        }
    }
    return files
}

type Fingerprint struct {
    Title       string
    Hash        string
    Modified    int64
    AddonDir    string
    Fingerprint uint32
}

func GetFingerprint(addonDir string) Fingerprint {
    fingerprint := Fingerprint{}
    fingerprint.AddonDir = addonDir
    fullAddonDir := wowDirPrefix + "/Interface/Addons/" + addonDir + "/"
    toFingerprint := []string{}
    fingerprints := []uint32{}
    files := GetFileListRecursive(fullAddonDir)
    for _, file := range files {
        if strings.HasSuffix(file, ".lua") || strings.HasSuffix(file, ".toc") || strings.HasSuffix(file, ".xml") {
            toFingerprint = append(toFingerprint, file)
        }
    }
    sort.Strings(toFingerprint)
    fmt.Println(toFingerprint)
    for _, s := range toFingerprint {
        fc := ReadFileAsBytes(s)
        fingerprints = append(fingerprints, mm.MurmurHash2(fc, 1))
    }
    compositeFingerprint := ""
    sort.Slice(fingerprints, func(i, j int) bool { return fingerprints[i] < fingerprints[j] })
    fmt.Println(fingerprints)
    for _, f := range fingerprints {
        compositeFingerprint += strconv.Itoa(int(f))
    }

    fmt.Println(compositeFingerprint)
    fingerprint.Fingerprint = mm.MurmurHash2([]byte(compositeFingerprint), 1)
    return fingerprint
}

func env(k string, failOnMissing bool) string {
    value := os.Getenv(k)
    if value != "" {
        return value
    }
    if failOnMissing {
        log.Fatalf("%v environment variable is not set.", k)
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    godotenv.Load()

    wowDirPrefix = env("DEBUG_WOW_RETAIL_DIR", false)

    fp := GetFingerprint("AutoRepair")
    fmt.Println(fp)
}
```

The output of the program looks something like this:

```
[Interface/Addons/AutoRepair/AutoRepair.lua Interface/Addons/AutoRepair/AutoRepair.toc Interface/Addons/AutoRepair/AutoRepair.xml]
[1276060341 2556314513 2805448843]
127606034125563145132805448843
{  0 AutoRepair 1798771541}
```

With that output, the final computed fingerprint is `1798771541`, but querying the API with that fingerprints yields no result, whereas it should yield the `AutoRepair` Addon.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get the answer? I thought curseforge used murmur2, but when i used a rust implementation, i got a different result.